# Crear relación laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo 3 tablas

**cliente** (id, id_usuario)

**usuario** (id,cliente_id)

**Orden** (id, cliente_id)

necesito crear una relación de tres tablas donde me traiga el id del usuario cuanto éste sea igual al id_usuario del cliente del usuario en sesion.

sería algo asi.

```
$Usuario = User::where('id', Cliente::(Auth::User()->id_usuario))->first();
```

Es la primera vez que me encuentro con una relación de este tipo y no logro la manera de resolverlo.

Comment: No entiendo, ¿esto qué tiene que ver con eager loading?

Comment: @Shaz tienes toda la razón, es solo Lazy Load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera.

en mi Modelo Orden

```
public function orden_cliente(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Cliente','id','cliente_id');
}
```

En mi controlador

```
$usuario = User::where('id', $orden->orden_cliente->id_usuario)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente debes en el modelo de la entidad que quieras relacionar colocar el siguiente codigo en el modelo de usuario

```
public function Cliente(){
return hasone(Usuario::class,'cliente_id','id');
}
```

te retornara todo los clientes que esten relacionados al usuario,
el mismo ejemplo aplica las otras entidades

puedes consultar mas al respecto en el siguiente link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many